# Snapchat Navigation Bar Style - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, snapchat

How does Snapchat make this navigation bar with the gradient background and rounded corners. Thanks!

I do not have a large enough reputation to post an image but it is the view that shows your snapchats to people, all the way to the left.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Sets background to a blank/empty image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    // Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    // Sets translucent background's color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    // Set translucent
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

    return true
}
```

In my UITableViewControllerClass:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView?.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    //Declare a gradient
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    //Set the two colors of your gradient
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    //Set it's location
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)!, height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you wish to have a gradient as a background a rounded corner for your table view.

Here is the code of my ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var backroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainingTableView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Change the corner radius to your liking
        viewContainingTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        //Make the backround of your 'navigation controller' transparent
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        //Declare a gradient
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        //Set the two colors of your gradient
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
        //Set it's location
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.backroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        //self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Change your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in your App Delegate to the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Sets background to a blank/empty image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    // Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    // Sets translucent background's color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    // Set translucent
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    return true
}
```

Here is my view hierarchy:

[image: View hierarchy]

Here is what it gives:

[image: View on iPhone]

To do it without the Storyboard, change your ViewController code to the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewContainingTableView = UIView()
    let navigationBarView = UINavigationBar()
    let topView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide

        view.addSubview(topView)
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        topView.addSubview(navigationBarView)
        navigationBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.navigationItem.title = "Test"

        let buttonNavBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(buttonAction))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonNavBar
        navigationBarView.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)

        view.addSubview(viewContainingTableView)
        viewContainingTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewContainingTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewContainingTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        viewContainingTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        viewContainingTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        viewContainingTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        viewContainingTableView.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainingTableView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainingTableView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainingTableView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainingTableView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        view.updateConstraints()

        //Change the corner radius to your liking
        viewContainingTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        //Make the backround of your 'navigation controller' transparent
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        //Declare a gradient
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        //Set the two colors of your gradient
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
        //Set it's location
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }

@objc func buttonAction() { 
        //Function of your button: add code to execute when button is pressed
    }    
}
```

Comment: This would work, however, I am trying to do this with a UICollectionViewController Class. Is there any possibility you would know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I have gotten pretty close. See image link   
         https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hUrrts2aWCRQNEFu0QvapuOkdkSpu-4W/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                            But the problem, as you can see, is that the corner radius is being applied wrong and the navigation bar does not cover the top bar thing (that displays time and more). I will put my code in the question above. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, you just have to add your navigation bar to the inside of your topView. That will keep the rounded corners and a covered status bar (see my updated answer)

Comment: Im sorry, you have been so much help but how would I do this without storyboard. Would you know? If not, I will just do some experimenting. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. If everybody on this platform was as helpful as you... wow! Haha, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your welcome! If you could just mark my answer as the correct one, I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: To add a button, you can see my answer, I added the code for it